# iOS 7: Custom Style Cell in Tableview: How to reference labels?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I was following a simple iOS 7 tutorial and using the standard subtitle cell type in a tableview, and got two labels for the Title and Subtitle. The labels were: `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel`

I now want to customize the cells in my tableView, so I switched the style to Custom, and created two labels on the storyboard. I then linked IBOutlets to those labels in the interface section of my .m file. It looks something like this:

```
@interface MasterViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailTextLabel;

@end
```

This is what my code to render my cells looks like, it is fairly standard, I think.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"KeyCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSDictionary *key = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *name = [key objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *type = [key objectForKey:@"type"];

cell.textLabel.text = name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Type : %@", type];    
return cell;
}
```

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: By creating an IBOutlet in your VC (your delegate) you have tried to link a single instance of those `UILabels`. Create a new `UITableViewCell` subclass and set your prototype cells to that class in IB.  Then drag your outlets across to that subclass. This is the only way using outlets that will work. As an aside, using Storyboards and Prototype cells means that your `if (cell == nil) { ...}` section is now redundant and can be removed as storyboards are guaranteed to return a cell.

Comment: Oh alright. That makes sense. How exactly do I create a new subclass and reference in my current code?

Answer (score 3):

By creating an IBOutlet in your VC (your delegate) you have tried to link a single instance of those UILabels.

Create a new UITableViewCell subclass and set your prototype cells to that class in IB. Then drag your outlets across to that subclass. This is the only way using outlets that will work.

Unfortunately I am a bit rushed for time otherwise I would post a full answer but here's how to do it:

`1.`Use `File->New->File...`;

`2.` Select `Cocoa Touch` and then `Objective-C Class`;

`3.` Enter Class Name and make sure the Subclass is of type `UITableViewCell`;

`4.` Click Next and create the classes in your project folder of choice.

`5.` Go to your storyboard, click on your prototype cell;

`6.` In the Utilities (right-hand) pane, click on the Identity Inspector (3rd icon) and in the class entry at the top enter the name of your new class.

`7.` Drag outlets to the .m file as you did before!

As an aside, using Storyboards and Prototype cells means that your `if (cell == nil) { ...}` section is now redundant and can be removed as storyboards are guaranteed to return a cell.

Comment: Tried all these steps, created a custom class homeTable which is a subclass of UITableViewCell, then I included homeTable.h in the masterviewcontroller file (where my tableview is). I referenced outlets in homeTable.h, but now I get a `Interface Builder StoryBoard compilation failed.` error. I have set the prototype cell to have the custom class (homeTable). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the prototype cell is of style custom and (for now) has two labels, which I have referenced as IBOutlets in the homeTable.h file.

Comment: Remove the IBOutlet links from the "masterviewcontroller" file AND make sure your remove those link references in the prototype cell (by right clicking on the objects that previously had been linked and removing the links to the "masterviewcontroller")

Answer (score 0):

You should give names to custom labels different from the standard.
Also, you need to subclass `UITableViewCell` and use it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.